# Tools for Designing & Modeling Complex Systems

Tags: algorithm, model, system, visualization

What are some good tools for designing & modeling complex systems?

*I'll leave the question open to some interpretation, to allow for a variety of answers.*

**Complex System:**
A complex system is a system composed of interconnected parts that as a whole exhibit one or more properties (behavior among the possible properties) not obvious from the properties of the individual parts.
-  [[Wikipedia - Complex Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_system)]

Comment: -1 Too vague. How about some specific application(s)?

Comment: +1 i'm keen on answers about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are fluent in writing discrete-event simulation code, or you have a particular subject-matter area for which there exists domain-specific simulation libraries, i would strongly suggest [NetLogo](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/index.shtml).

NetLogo is a platform for Agent-based simulation; the term also describes the DSL used in this platform. Aside from the documentation supplied in NetLogo itself, Seth Tisue and Uri Wilensky have written an excellent [introduction](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.117.949&rank=2) to NetLogo.

NetLogo is widely used among the community of Agent-Based modelers--for instance, it was featured in a 2010 Conference Proceedings paper titled *Software Tools for Analysis and Modelling in Complex Systems*. (The link to the paper is [here](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/papers/2010/chapter_ABM_NA.pdf)--careful it's a direct link to the pdf file).

Over the past decade, NetLogo has been used in a large variety of practical applications, including [Financial Markets](http://ideas.repec.org/p/pra/mprapa/23923.html#author), [Clinical Medicine](http://Wandling,%20M.,%20&%20An,%20G.%20%282010%29.%20Multi-Scale%20Dynamic%20Knowledge%20Representation%20of%20Pulmonary%20Inflammation%20with%20an%20Agent-Based%20Model%3a%20from%20Gene%20Regulation%20to%20Clinical%20Phenomenon.%20Journal%20of%20Surgical%20Research%20%28ASC%20Abstracts%20Issue%29,%20158%282%29:381.), [Network Architecture](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.170.5000&rank=3) and [Diagnostics](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.25.3452&rank=1), and [Traffic Simulation](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.170.4215&rank=3).

A few facts about **NetLogo**:

- a GUI-driven integrated simulation
  environment
- free and open source
- stable and mature (development began
  in 1999)
- actively supported (by Northwestern University, for coursework use)
- excellent and large body of
  documentation
- *many* working [***code examples***](http://www.turtlezero.com/wiki/doku.php) (complete
  models) are [bundled](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/index.cgi) with the base install of NetLogo

To me, the last bullet was the most compelling reason to try NetLogo--this large and diverse library of pre-built, complete simulations meant a relatively painless learning path. In addition, these served as a valuable library of *template models* from which i could select a few and modify rather than starting from a blank page.

Comment: And not used anywhere outside of narrow academic applications.  Never heard of it; I'd be surprised if you could cite a single significant commercial application that's used it.

Comment: Never heard of it? Are you familiar with any simulation tools? Your answer suggest not. W/r/t NetLogo and applications in the real world, i edited my answer to include a half dozen or so (with links to the sources), but there are many more.

Answer (score 4):

If NetLogo alone does not meet your needs, look at [the available extensions](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Extensions).

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider Wolfram Mathematica or System Modeler. Not only does Mathematica have a very nice cellular automata modeling capability built-in, but there is also a large body of [Demonstrations](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/) that will help you as you try to build agent-based or cellular automata modeling. In addition, Mathematica can also model dynamical networks. Finally, [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/BySubject/AppliedMathematics/ComplexSystems/) is a website listing how Mathematica has been used to model complexity in conference proceedings and other applications.